# XKB configuration file documentation?

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, keyboard-layout, documentation, xkb

I'm trying to debug some keyboard issues on an Ubuntu Linux desktop. I'm reading XKB configuration files at this point, but I have yet to find the documentation on these files. Instructions like this are not exactly self explanatory:

```
interpret ISO_Level3_Shift+AnyOf(all) {
    virtualModifier= LevelThree;
    useModMapMods=level1;
    action= SetMods(modifiers=LevelThree,clearLocks);
};
```

Does anyone know where this file format is documented?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same for a while and haven't found so far a documentation that I could advice. I suspect that there is no user friendly documentation about XKB configuration files as of now (2022). There are pieces of information scattered across several sources. I can only summarize what I've found so far.

##### Arch Linux Wiki

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/X_keyboard_extension - this page is probably the best thing that I've found. But it's too short, incomplete and often doesn't have explanations of examples.

##### x.org

https://www.x.org/wiki/XKB/ - this page seems to be an official list of documents related to XKB but... some of the "helpful links" don't work already, others are too short and don't go into details. It's possible to use wayback machine though to open the broken links.

At the bottom of the page there are specs for the protocol but these specs are more about c++ development side of things rather than about how to modify config files. Among these documents I would advice to look into the last one - "XKB protocol specification". But it's not easy for reading. You know there is a difference between specs where the primary goal is to be correct and books where the primary goal is to be easy to understand for the reader.

A more user friendly document is the "An Unreliable Guide to XKB Configuration". But it's far from being complete.

A more complete document is "en: http://pascal.tsu.ru/en/xkb/ | ru: [http://pascal.tsu.ru/other/xkb/"](http://pascal.tsu.ru/other/xkb/%22) but the link doesn't work. I recovered it from the wayback machine and converted to markdown here: https://github.com/barsv/ivan-pascal-xkb/ But it was originally written in Russian and later translated by Ivan Pascal into English. The translation is neither easy to read nor complete.

Answer (score -1):

[This](https://www.charvolant.org/doug/xkb/html/node5.html#SECTION00054000000000000000) has full documentation on the snippet you've provided.

I don't know what you're trying to debug but here's my [config](https://github.com/jnzigg/dotfiles/tree/master/.config/xkb) with it's own comprehensive README for reference. There's some additional resources in there as well should you need it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1224870)

Comment: @DaveM Well they didn't say what they were trying to debug and the snippet they provided was pretty abstracted from the implementation. I'd just be regurgitating the whole docs to try and explain it. Also, I don't understand the docs that deeply but I am sure that the link I provided covered what they asked compared to those given in the other answer. I deemed this better than just not having any better resources available here. If this is discouraged despite so then note taken.

Comment: Thanks for the docs! I agree that my question was generic, as I couldn't find documentation and I figured that might be of interest to others. The issue I was trying to debug turned out to be this exact issue: https://web.archive.org/web/20140123154001/http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1022454   I have not found a workaround, but if there's something I could do in XKB config to work around the stray Control_L event as mentioned there, that'd be interesting to know!

Comment: I've added a more specific question as well, it's on https://superuser.com/questions/1823940/use-xkb-to-work-around-stray-key-events