# Use XKB to work around stray key events?

Tags: linux, keyboard, vmware, xkb

Due to complex infrastructure, I am experiencing an issue where hitting AltGr on my keyboard results in a stray Control_L signal being received on the Linux desktop on the receiving end. The issue has apparently been around in some way at least since 2012, and is described in [VMware KB article 1022454](https://web.archive.org/web/20140123154001/http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1022454) (only available through archive.org).

I can confirm that the manual workaround mentioned there works:

> Use this key combination for AltGr+:
>
> - Press and hold AltGr.
> - Press and release Ctrl.
>
> **Note: The Ctrl key nullifies the Control_L event.**
>
> - Press and release <key>.
> - Release AltGr.

The other workarounds mentioned are irrelevant/outdated/don't work.

I can't do anything about the infrastructure components in between. Is there anything I can do in my XKB config to ignore the stray Control_L that is received in these cases?

I don't think I ever combine Ctrl and AltGr, so simply ignoring Control_L in this specific case would probably solve the problem for me.